# Error: Request failed with status code 404 Spring-Security enabled

Tags: spring-security

I am developing an App in FrontEnd (ReactJS, AXIOS) and Backend (Spring).
When I did a post to do login with success with :

```
axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/login",
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
        })
```

I got this answer in Postman

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-05-23T01:48:27.986+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/"
}
```

I have these filters

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/api/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/api/logout").permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
```

I want to receive just in /api/login the data of the user validated.
Can it achieve that with the filters only or do I need to create a controller?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with two things.
I created a endpoint with
This code give me the actual user :

```
@RequestMapping("/actualuser")
    public Object actualUser(){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println(auth.getDetails());
    return auth.getPrincipal();
    }
```

and I this filter in .formLogin() and logout .logout()

```
.successForwardUrl("/api/actualuser")
```